# Nested Dataframe loses format after mutating with ifelse-condition

Tags: r, if-statement, nested

I'm trying to mutate a new variable in a nested dataframe with an ifelse-condition. But the problem is that after implementing the ifelse-condition the nested dataframe turns into a list.
I want to show this problem with the `iris` dataset:

Here you can see the original nested format:

```
iris %>% nest(data = -Species)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Species    data             
  <fct>      <list>           
1 setosa     <tibble [50 x 4]>
2 versicolor <tibble [50 x 4]>
3 virginica  <tibble [50 x 4]>
```

And now I want to mutate a new variable in the nested dataframes:

```
iris %>%
  nest(data = -Species) %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, function(x)
    x %>% mutate(`Sepal.Length^2` = Sepal.Length^2)))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Species    data             
  <fct>      <list>           
1 setosa     <tibble [50 x 5]>
2 versicolor <tibble [50 x 5]>
3 virginica  <tibble [50 x 5]>
```

This code works. The `data`-column is as desired in the tibble-format.

But if I insert the ifelse-condition now, the tibble-format is lost:

```
iris %>%
  nest(data = -Species) %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, function(x)
    ifelse(!is.na(x), x %>% mutate(`Sepal.Length^2` = Sepal.Length^2), NA)))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Species    data        
  <fct>      <list>      
1 setosa     <list [200]>
2 versicolor <list [200]>
3 virginica  <list [200]>
```

I want to keep the `tibble`-format even with the `ifelse`-condition.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think you must create the new column first and then do the ifelse condition. So something like `... map(... function(x) mutate(x, ifelse(...)))`

Comment: In my original dataset this is not possible, because there are some `NA`-values in the `data`-colum. So first I have to "filter" the data with the ifelse-function.

Comment: But you are not mutating only when there are not NAs. You are mutating and then you handle the conditions. So `ifelse(!is.na(x), x^2, x)` . But maybe I m missing something with your explanation

Comment: It works with the `if`-function instead of the `ifelse`-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first step of the `map()` computation, i.e. data in `setosa`, the input `x` of your custom function is actually

```
x <- iris[1:50, 1:4]
```

Then you put `x` into `ifelse()`

```
ifelse(!is.na(x),                                        # part 1
       x %>% mutate(`Sepal.Length^2` = Sepal.Length^2),  # part 2
       NA)                                               # part 3
```

The first part is `!is.na(x)`, which returns `50x4=200` logical values. Hence, the second and third parts will be recycled to length 200. However, the second part, i.e.

```
x %>% mutate(`Sepal.Length^2` = Sepal.Length^2)
```

is a `tibble` with 5 variables, which is also a `list` with length 5, so each variable in this `tibble` will be recycled 40 times and subsequently a `list` with length 200 will be created. That is why you get 3 lists of length 200.

---

In your case, `ifelse()` may not be applicable. You can adjust it to

```
iris %>%
  nest(data = -Species) %>%
  add_row(Species = "example", data = NA) %>% 
  mutate(data = map(data, function(x) {
    if(is.data.frame(x))
      x %>% mutate(`Sepal.Length^2` = Sepal.Length^2)
    else
      NULL
  }))

# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#   Species    data             
#   <chr>      <list>           
# 1 setosa     <tibble [50 × 5]>
# 2 versicolor <tibble [50 × 5]>
# 3 virginica  <tibble [50 × 5]>
# 4 example    <NULL>
```

Make sure that the condition in `if()` must be a single logical value.

---

Grateful to **@27ϕ9** for a neater version with `map_if()`:

```
iris %>%
  nest(data = -Species) %>%
  add_row(Species = "example", data = NA) %>% 
  mutate(data = map_if(data, is_tibble,
                       ~ mutate(.x, `Sepal.Length^2` = Sepal.Length^2),
                       .else = NULL))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have `NA`-values in the `data`-colum in my original dataset. Therefore your code does not work in my case.

Comment: This example-dataset would be better basis: `iris %>% nest(data = -Species)%>%
  add_row(Species="example",data=NA)`

Comment: In my case it works now with the `if`-function but not with the `ifelse`-function. I can't explain why. Furthermore I now using `is_tibble(x)`: `if(is_tibble(x)) x %>% mutate("Sepal.Length^2" = Sepal.Length^2)`

Comment: @TobKel `is_tibble(x)` is great. Note that `ifelse()` is not equivalent to `if...else...`. They apply on different situations. You can search `?ifelse` for more detail.

Comment: @27ϕ9 Thank for your reply. But I tend to answer this question with the minimal revision of the OP's code, and focus on the difference of `ifelse()` and `if...else`. I'll add your suggestion into my answer. It's a good point.